# Understanding Denormalization in Relational Databases?

Tags: database, postgresql, rdbms, database-normalization, denormalization

Let's say I have tables like below in NF3

Table Name: **Address**

- line1
- line2
- state_id

Table Name: **State**

- id
- name
- country_id

Table Name: **Country**

- id
- name

Now I want to denormalize this table so that read will be faster and I don't need to JOIN multiple tables, **but I couldn't able understand what is denormalization is.**

Example 1) Do I need to keep tables like above in 3NF, and extra columns to Address like state_name, country_name so the resulting table looks like below.

Table Name **Address**

- line1
- line2
- state_name
- country_name
- state_id

Or

Example 2) Do I need to remove state_id from the `Address` table and keep `state_name` and `country_name`.

Table Name **Address**

- line1
- line2
- state_name
- country_name

From the above 2 examples, which is denormalization?

Comment: `state` / `country` are most often static data (practically unchanged). you don't need `state_id`.

Comment: got it, but for example, state and country are changing frequently, what is exactly denormalization, from my example is it case 1 or case 2, my doubt is about denormalization from normalization.

Comment: I can't understand why you need `state_id`. can you add some context? What problem does `state_id` solve in 1 case?

Comment: It's not about state_id,  My question is about denormalization, for that, I take an address as an example. I have two examples above in that which is denormalized form?

Comment: got it, but I'm late((( see the answers below. I think they are understandable. good luck!

Comment: Give definition of "denormalization" & ask a question about the 1st place you are stuck applying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://Denormalization):

> Denormalization is the process of trying to improve the read performance of a database, at the expense of losing some write performance, by **adding redundant copies** of data or by grouping data.

So, by adding `state_name` to the `Address` table, you have denormalized the database.

It doesn't matter whether you eliminate `state_id` or not. The simple act of added a column like `state_name` that has a lot of rows with the same value, makes the database denormalized.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples you show are denormalized.  For practical purposes you would want to store the state_id.  Otherwise you'll lose connection to the state table and thus unable to update the state name (and country name).

Here is a page that seems to address your problem.

https://rubygarage.org/blog/database-denormalization-with-examples

Best regards,
Bjarni